# Loading C++ dll in python doesn't work with C++ libs

Tags: python, c++, c, dll

So I am trying to make a C/C++ dll for a project but any C++ library I include in my header, ends up causing loading problems when I try to load it using ctypes in python. I'm guessing maybe ctypes doesn't have c++ libs paths included? 
I made a simple demonstration to my problem.

##### init2.h: Generic Header file for dll and execs using the dll

```cpp
#ifndef INIT2_H
#define INIT2_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
void func11();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

##### init2.cc: dll code (loads fine)

```cpp
// This works fine
#include "init2.h"

void func11() {
    printf("Func11\n");
}
```

##### init.c: exe code that loads dll

```c
#include "init2.h"

int main() {
    func11();
    return 0;
}
```

##### Makefile

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c11 -g
CCFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11 -g

all: libmain.dll main

main.o: init2.cc
    g++ $(CCFLAGS) init2.cc -fpic -c -o main.o

libmain.dll: main.o
    g++ $(CCFLAGS) -shared main.o -o libmain.dll

main: init.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -L. -lmain init.c -o main

clean: 
    del *.o *.exe *.dll *.txt
```

##### script.py

```py
from ctypes import *

lib = CDLL('D:\Projects\Learning-C++\libmain.dll')
lib.func11()
```

The above compiles, links and loads fine in the generated main.exe and script.py. The problem occurs when I add a c++ lib in my dll.

##### init2.cc: With iostream (loads in main.exe only)

```cpp
#include "init2.h"
#include <iostream>

void func11() {
    std::cout << "Func11\n";
}
```

Compiling that into the dll, while everything stays the same loads fine into the main.exe (init.c code) but gives me the following loading error in script.py.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\Learning-C++\script.py", line 3, in <module>
    lib = CDLL('D:\Projects\Learning-C++\libmain.dll')
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'D:\Projects\Learning-C++\libmain.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

How can I fix this? My bad if these seems obvious, but I'm fairly new to C++ and haven't got the integration down yet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you get invalid escape sequence `\P` in python file? It is strange.

Comment: I usually put all the program dependencies in the same folder to start troubleshooting these things.  Then check dependency walker or `dumpbin /dependents your_dll_file.dll`

Comment: @Matt thanks, that helped. I ended up using os.add_dll_directory to add the directory where the c++ std lib is defined.

Comment: @MazenBahgat dependencies can be tricky to find without those tools - and dumpbin seems to be much cleaner than the ancient Dependency Walker most people still use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as I expected due to cdll not able to find the C++ library. The file name for my case was libstdc++-6.dll. Which is located in the bin folder in my compiler's directory. To make cdll search for the dependencies in that folder I did the following:

```py
import os

# add dependency directory
os.add_dll_directory('C:\\Program Files\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin')

# load the dll 
lib = CDLL('D:\\Projects\\Learning-C++\\libmain.dll')
lib.func11()
```

The dll may have many dependencies located in other directories e.g. You defined libDLL.dll and bin/libDependency.dll. You will need to add the /path/to/dir/bin directory using the above method if you're trying to load libDLL.dll in python.
 You can find all the dependencies of a dll using dependency walker or
`dumpbin /dependents libDLL.dll`
in the VS dev powershell.